# Async scripts in header making other external scripts and functions called in body throw "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, asynchronous

In the header of a site I am working on, I have a whole bunch of external javascripts (jQuery, plugins, a main js file for the site's functions, etc) being called. I have decided to put the `async="async"` tag on them to improve performance on Chrome and Firefox.

I have noticed that after doing this, some functions that are called in various parts of the site's body are being flagged as "not defined" in the error console. I tested the site in IE and Opera (browsers that don't support the async attribute) and it works just fine. I then removed the async attribute from all of the scripts and it worked fine again in Chrome and Firefox.

I'm guessing my use of the async attribute is causing some scripts to be finished loading before others are called, and the ones that have finished loading are scripts that have dependencies (like jQuery or a plugin) that have not finished loading which would throw the "undefined" error I'm seeing.

If my understanding on this is wrong, please correct me. If what I think is going on is what's actually happening, is there anyway around this while keeping the async attribute on all of the script tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want stuff to load in a specific order `async` removes that order and they load in the order in which they load which you most probably *do not want*.

Comment: That makes sense but then how does the async attribute prove to be effective for any kind of script? It seems a lot of scripts rely on events and certain objects being "ready" and it seems that the async attribute would screw a lot of things up in those situations...

Comment: @Aaron im not sure. i dont use them personally because i always want my code to load in the order in which i have placed it. i definitely want libraries to **always** be loaded 1st because they might be needed for the rest of the js code

Comment: I see. Maybe I was expecting too much out of this attribute. I guess it really is a good idea to load libraries and plugins right off the bat. I will stick to doing that and load other less important scripts asynchronously. Thanks for your help!